# how to count characters before/after the first space in line?

Tags: shell-script, shell

I want to count the number of characters after the first space. So for example, the line may be like this: 
*Iam a bunny*

N = The number of characters after the first space is 7 (a bunny)
So I came up with one way. That is, count the number of characters before the first space and the space itself = P. Then N = length of the line - P = 11 - 4 = 7 (length of "Iam " is 4)

```
count_first_part() {
line=$1
count=0
echo "$1" | grep -o . >file1.txt
while read -r linee; do
  if [[ "$linee" != [^[:space:]] ]]; then
  ((count++))
  else
    ((count++))
    break
  fi

done <file1.txt
echo "$count" }
```

```
count_length_of_line() {
string=$1
count=$(echo "$string" | wc -c)
}
```

```
p=$(count_first_part "Iam a bunny") 
l=$(count_length_of_line "Iam a bunny")
n=$l-$p
echo "$n"
```

However, the function count_first_part() returns 1 and count_length_of_line() returns length+1 (which is wrong). Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a variable contains the string:

```
str="Iam a bunny"
```

It might be as simple as:

```
$ before="${str%% *} "; after=${str#* }
$ echo "\"$before\"=${#before} \"$after\"=${#after}"
"Iam "=4 "a bunny"=7
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `read` into multiple variables from a here-string:

```
$ str="Iam a bunny"
$ read -r first rest <<<"$str"
$ echo "${#first} ${#rest}"
3 7
```

You can add a space to first like `first+=" "` if you want.

This technique will not accomodate *multiple* whitespace between the words.

Perhaps a more robust technique would be a regular expression:

```
$ if [[ $str =~ ([^[:blank:]]+[[:blank:]]+)(.*) ]]; then
    first=${BASH_REMATCH[1]} rest=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
  fi
$ echo "${#first} ${#rest}"
4 7
```